# Is there a way to manually install and maintain an EPG database from titantv for use in the old EyeTV software?

Tags: macos, preferences

I still use my old EyeTV hybrid and it works great. However, I miss titanTV integration for automatic recording. Is there a way to restore integration of the titantv guide data? I found the EPG database in EyeTV and was thinking it might be possible to drop in a copy from titantv? Has anyone tried to do that before?

The details:

- OS: MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
- EyeTV Software version: EyeTV 3 (3.6.8)
- Dongle version: EyeTV Hybrid
- EyeTV Hybrid Driver: AMD ATI Theater T507

The EyeTV software used to support TitanTV (http://www.titantv.com) as a free TV Guide service alternative, but they dropped that support with version 3.  That service basically populated an EPG database (Electronic Programming Guide).  My bet/hope is that this EPG database is standardized between the various guide service providers or at least could be converted.

I found the EPG database in `/Library/Application Support/EyeTV/Shared/EyeTVEPG.db` and was wondering if I could obtain or convert the guide info from titantv.com and drop it there.

Basic info:

EyeTV is a USB dongle into which you can plug in a digital or analog Coax.  The EyeTV software basically turns your Mac into a DVR for the airwaves.  I can go to TitanTV.com and click the record icon for any show, which downloads a file that auto-opens in EyeTV and it automatically schedules the show to record.  However, with the former guide integration of titantv into eyetv, you could tell it to auto-record any show by a particular name whenever it is on, as opposed to scheduling individual airings.  I can schedule recordings based on time and channel and have it repeat every week, but the former functionality used to be able to record only new episodes and not reruns.  That's the functionality I wish to restore.  The older software version did this, but I was forced to upgrade to version 3 because version 2 was flaking out.

Comment: I don't use the software but according to the manual you should be able to use TitanTV Remote Scheduling (https://saturn.geniatech.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Eyetv3softwaremanual-english.pdf, page 58). Not directly what you are asking for, but would this help as well?

Comment: Yes, I already use that, however it doesn't let you set up automatic recordings of shows with specific names whenever they air on any channel like it used to do via titantv. And geniatech dropped support for this old software produced by Elgato (which was bought out by geniatech). I just added a "basic info" thing at the bottom to clarify what I want in this regard.

Comment: And I believe that that manual is old. There’s no longer a titantv option in the guide preferences. The recordings I set up via titantv can no longer be done remotely. You have to do it on the Mac via the titantv website. Although, I sometimes VNC in to do it.

Comment: I emailed Geniatech back in February to inquire about TitanTV guide support after I upgraded the software and this was their response: Hello Robert,

Thank you for contacting us.

I am sorry to tell you that eyetv does not support TitanTV. 

Kind regards,

Angela 

Geniatech EyeTV Support Team

Comment: It looks like it might be possible to download the titantv EPG data using their API. I wonder if anyone has written a downloader: http://data.titantv.com/dataservice.asmx?

Comment: I would post that as an answer. The only thing that gets an answer quicker than an excellent question is when someone can prove another answer wrong.

Comment: Well, technically, I don’t know if a download using their API can just be dropped in to replace the EyeTVEPG.db file. I tried looking through the API, but it’s pretty thick and I don’t want to do it if someone else has already gone to the effort. I found a github repo of a java project where they use the API to search for shows using a Cron job. It wasn’t clear to me though if it could do what I want and their code base was also thick.